# VBScript, HTA - INI Parsing, allow inline comments

Tags: vbscript, ini, hta

I am currently working on a game launcher and have working code borrowed from the Internet to be able to parse an INI. All is working excellently save for one issue.

It cannot parse inline comments on the ini file.

Example:

```
[Window] 
Width=800
```

Is parsed fine and without issue, great.

```
[Window]
Width=800 ; width in pixels
```

But the above is not, I need it to be able to stop reading the line at detecting a ; if possible.

Here is my full HTA code:

```
<Html>
<Head>

    <Title>Installer</Title>
    <Meta Http-Equiv="x-ua-compatible" Content="ie=9">
    <Link Rel="stylesheet" Type="text/css" Href="image/appStyles.css" Media="screen" />

    <Script Language="VBScript" Type="Text/VBScript">
    '--  Scripts to be carried out before the installer loads in.

    '--  Functions  --'

    Function ReadIni( myFilePath, mySection, myKey )
    ' This function returns a value read from an INI file

    ' Examples
    ' ReadIni( "settings.config", "Section1", "Keyname1" )
    ' ReadIni( "settings.config", "Section1", "Keyname2" )
    ' ReadIni( "settings.config", "Section2", "Keyname1" )
    ' ReadIni( "settings.config", "Section4", "Keyname2" )

    Const ForReading   = 1
    Const ForWriting   = 2
    Const ForAppending = 8

    Dim intEqualPos
    Dim objFSO, objIniFile
    Dim strFilePath, strKey, strLeftString, strLine, strSection

    Set objFSO = CreateObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" )

    ReadIni     = ""
    strFilePath = Trim( myFilePath )
    strSection  = Trim( mySection )
    strKey      = Trim( myKey )

    If objFSO.FileExists( strFilePath ) Then
        Set objIniFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile( strFilePath, ForReading, False )
        Do While objIniFile.AtEndOfStream = False
            strLine = Trim( objIniFile.ReadLine )

        ' Check if section is found in the current line
        If LCase( strLine ) = "[" & LCase( strSection ) & "]" Then
            strLine = Trim( objIniFile.ReadLine )

        ' Parse lines until the next section is reached
            Do While Left( strLine, 1 ) <> "["

        ' Find position of equal sign in the line
            intEqualPos = InStr( 1, strLine, "=", 1 )

        If intEqualPos > 0 Then
            strLeftString = Trim( Left( strLine, intEqualPos - 1 ) )

        ' Check if item is found in the current line
            If LCase( strLeftString ) = LCase( strKey ) Then
                ReadIni = Trim( Mid( strLine, intEqualPos + 1 ) )

                ' In case the item exists but value is blank
                 If ReadIni = "" Then
                    ReadIni = " "
                 End If

                ' Abort loop when item is found
                    Exit Do
                End If
            End If

            ' Abort if the end of the INI file is reached
                If objIniFile.AtEndOfStream Then Exit Do

            ' Continue with next line
               strLine = Trim( objIniFile.ReadLine )
                Loop
                    Exit Do
                End If
        Loop
            objIniFile.Close
        Else
            ' WScript.Echo strFilePath & " doesn't exists. Exiting..."
            ' Wscript.Quit 1
        End If
    End Function


    '--  Subroutines  --'

    '--  Resize & move app to center
    Sub SetWindow( WidthX,HeightY )
        Self.ResizeTo WidthX, HeightY
        Self.MoveTo (screen.Width - WidthX)/2, (screen.Height - HeightY)/2
    End Sub

    '--  Close app
    Sub WinClose
        Self.Close
    End Sub


    '--  Startup  --'

    '--  Read the configuration settings.

    IniFile = "settings.config"
    WinWidth = ReadIni( IniFile, "Window", "Width" )
    WinHeight = ReadIni( IniFile, "Window", "Height" )

    '--  Set Window size
    SetWindow WinWidth, WinHeight


    </Script>

    <Hta:Application    Id="Installer"  ApplicationName="Installer"     Version="0.1"

        SingleInstance="Yes"
        Icon="image/appIcon.ico" 
        Caption="No"
        Border="None"
        InnerBorder="No"
        ContextMenu="No"
        SysMenu="None"
        Scroll="No"
        Selection="No"

     />

</Head>

<Body>

    <Div Id="status">Hello</Div>


<Script Language="VBScript" Type="Text/VBScript">
'--  Scripts that require access to the DOM...

    '-- Startup
    document.getElementById("status").InnerHTML = "Idle"
    document.title = ReadIni( IniFile, "App", "Title" )


</Script>

<Script Type="Text/Javascript">
//--  Javascripts that require access to the DOM...

    window.onload = function() {
        var a = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
            a.ondragstart = function() { return false; }
    }
</Script>

</Body>
</Html>
```

Any help you guys could provide would be great, thank you!

Comment: Not exactly related, but the JS part won't work. `getElementsByTagName()` returns a HTMLCollection, which is an array-like object. You've to iterate it through to access the image elements, the collection itself doesn't have `ondragstart` method.

Comment: Oh, Yes I was tinkering with that to apply it to any image but after realised I was not going to go with multiple images within the launcher (was going to use an image for a close icon) but decided to just use CSS instead. Hence I changed it back to `var a = document.getElementById("Logo");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WinWidth = Trim(Split(ReadIni( IniFile, "Window", "Width" ), ";")(0))
```

Split the value using the semicolon, take the first element in the list and remove start/end spaces if present

Comment: Thank you very much, but that is editing the code that reads the INI, not the code that is actually doing the reading. Can code to prevent the line being read after a ; not be done within the ReadIni function? Thanks for your efforts so far.

Comment: @Ctrlaltdenied, you can place the same `Split(..` inside the `ReadIni` function, but then you could have a problem: How will you read a value that could contain a semicolon? Under this scenario I decided to do the `Split` on the returned value, not in the code that gets the line content.

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification, there would not be any semi colons used within the ini file for values anyways. It is only there to read settings, as the launcher/installer is configurable in terms of this. I just wanted to be able to comment inline on the individual values for the users of it rather than doing comments as separate lines. The main issue, is currently, if ; is present after a value, it causes the values to be read incorrectly and causes failures in the app.

Comment: @Ctrlaltdenied, the return value (if found) is readed in the line `ReadIni = Trim( Mid( strLine, intEqualPos + 1 ) )`. Change it to `ReadIni = Trim(Split(Mid( strLine, intEqualPos + 1 ), ";")(0))` But, as said, remember you will not be able to retrieve data that contain a semicolon